# Why the first eigenfunction of laplacian is nonvanishing inside the domain?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've seen several posts tring to generalize the fact that the first eigenfunction of laplacian is the only nonvanishing eigenfuction, but I've no idea how to prove that fact nor I could find any reference of giving a proof.
I guess the argument should be simple, but I just can't come up with it.

I'll really appreciate if anyone can give me good references or simply sketch the idea of how to prove that fact. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See Theorem 1.6 in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/LapEig/lecpdf/lecture7.pdf